# SQL statement that will return result after 16 days of the month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server with some information.

I want to write a SQL statement that will display this information after **16 days of every month**.

So at the beginning of the month the query should execute nothing until the 16 days have passed.

Comment: You are looking to schedule your query? Depending on the OS there are numerous ways to do this.

Comment: can you please provide sample schema and sample data

Comment: Hey there, welcome to SO! Your question is missing crucial details and you won't get a lot of help this way, unfortunately. What is obvious to you, isn't obvious to everyone else. [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](Here's official guide how to ask good questions).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to as part of the `where` clause:

```
datepart(dd,getdate()) > 16
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you don't want to data coming up, until the current day is > 16. I have provided asample query.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES (1),(2)) AS t(ID)
WHERE DATEPART(day,GETDATE()) > 16
```